# MassTransit: is it possible to have a publish-only app?

Tags: c#, masstransit

It appears that MassTransit requires every app that interacts with the bus to have an input queue, even if it's a pure producer:

**Consumer**

```
ServiceBusFactory.New(_=>
{
    _.UseRabbitMq();
    _.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/consumer");
    _.Subscribe(...);
});
```

**Producer**

```
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(_=>
{
    _.UseRabbitMq();
    _.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/producer");
});
```

This is redundant and can cause configuration problems for us since we have a complex application and will have competing consumers.

Is it possible to configure a bus without a receiving queue for a pure producer?, i.e:

```
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(_=>
{
    _.UseRabbitMq();
});

bus.Publish(...);
```

**EDIT:**

OK It appears that I might have slightly misunderstood the documentation's emphasis on using multiple queues, this appears to work just fine:

**Consumer**

```
ServiceBusFactory.New(_=>
{
    _.UseRabbitMq();
    _.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/company");
    _.Subscribe(...);
});
```

**Producer**

```
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(_=>
{
    _.UseRabbitMq();
    _.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/company");
});

bus.Publish(...);
```

Since the publish did not subscribe to any messages, it does not eat them or anything like that. I guess the documentation's gotcha was referring to the non-competing scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Some more insight here from Dru Sellers, one of the authors of MassTransit:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/masstransit-discuss/_bnDRDGWLcc